# "team_name" cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I am having an unusual error with trying to return a string in my code. I am very new to java so I don't sometimes understand the ins and outs of how classes and returning values/assignment of values works. Any advice would be very helpful! Thank you :)

```
package videogaem;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TeamName {

    public String getTeamName() {

        boolean valid_name = false;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (valid_name == false) {

            System.out.println("Enter team name here: ");
            String team_name = reader.nextLine();

            int name_length = team_name.length();

            if (name_length >= 3 && name_length < 10) {
                System.out.println(team_name + "... Sweet as name!");
                valid_name = true;
                return team_name;
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("Name must be within 2 - 10 characters! :^)");
                valid_name = false;
            }

        }

        reader.close();
        return team_name; /// <<< team_name is underlined red with the error

        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TeamName team = new TeamName();
        team.getTeamName();
    }

}
```

Comment: Because the variable is declared inside the while block. Java have block based scoping.

Comment: Make sure the scanner is closed. In if statement you simply returning the team_name you have not closed the reader. It's opened, so first close the reader and then return the team_name. Check the updated answer below

Comment: @Blake, For record you need to accept one answer which you think really helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the variable name outside the `while` condition. You have declared the variable name inside the while loop, so it's scope lies inside the while loop.Make sure the scanner is closed. In if statement you simply returning the `team_name` you have not closed the reader. It's opened, so first close the reader and then return the `team_name`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TeamName {

    public String getTeamName() {
        String team_name = null;

        boolean valid_name = false;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (valid_name == false) {

            System.out.println("Enter team name here: ");
            team_name = reader.nextLine();

            int name_length = team_name.length();

            if (name_length >= 3 && name_length < 10) {
                System.out.println(team_name + "... Sweet as name!");
                valid_name = true;
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("Name must be within 2 - 10 characters! :^)");
                valid_name = false;
            }

        }
        reader.close();
        return team_name;
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TeamName team = new TeamName();
        team.getTeamName();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the **getTeamName()** method declear the **String team_name** ..

remove from the inner scope and right just before this scope.